# How to get users email address using SharePoint REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using the following code to get the current logged in user to a SP page. I'm only able to get the Title. How can I get the email address as well? Thank you.

```
// Get current user
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://.../_api/web/currentuser?$select=Title,User/ID,User/EMail&$expand=User",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose","Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function(data) {
        username = data.d.Title;
        console.log(data.d);
        console.log("user name: " + username);
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = username;
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error occurred trying to get user id");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve email by REST API in the way as you posted you can simply change `url` parameter to `https://.../_api/web/currentuser?$select=Title,Email`

So your code will be

```
// Get current user
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://.../_api/web/currentuser?$select=Title,Email",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose","Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function(data) {
        username = data.d.Title;
        console.log(data.d);
        console.log("user name: " + username);
        console.log("user email: " + data.d.Email);
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = username;
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error occurred trying to get user id");
    }
});
```

Also, there are a lot of another ways to retrieve current user properties:

1. Get all properties of current user:

> http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties

2. Get single property of current user:

> http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties/Email

OR

> http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=Email

3. Get Multiple Properties for the current user:

> http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=Email,AccountName

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the REST API to get the current user's display name or email address. You can get them from a JavaScript variable named _spPageContextInfo that is injected into each Classic SharePoint page. Use _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName to get the currect user's name and _spPageContextInfo.userEmail to get their email address.

You can get lots of other valuable information from _spPageContextInfo. See [Using _spPageContextInfo to Determine the Current SharePoint Context in Script](https://sympmarc.com/2013/03/26/using-_sppagecontextinfo-to-determine-the-current-sharepoint-context-in-script/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Email only. No need to use User/EMail.

Try below.

```
// Get current user
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://.../_api/web/currentuser?$select=Title,Email",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose","Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function(data) {
        username = data.d.Title;
        console.log(data.d);
        console.log("user name: " + username);
        console.log("user Email: " + data.d.Email);
        document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = username;
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error occurred trying to get user id");
    }
});
```